# How to stop every 10 questions?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have a list of 100 questions in my database.
I also have an array of shuffled questions with a index size of 0-99 which I use to reference to the database. It's so I don't shuffled the database.

My question is that the game starts at question 0 (10 for 2nd round, 20 for 3rd etc). I tried using a x mod 10 but I have it ordered so I check whether or not the question I'm up to has exceeded the limit for the round. (This stops the 11th question displaying on the screen) But since the game starts at question 0, the mod result is 0 and that would mean the end of the round. I need it to run question 0-9 stop at 10. next round 10-19 stop at 20.. etc

I don't want to have to hardcode it like:
run question except if question number is 0, 10, 20... 80, 90 100.
in one big if statement.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Yeah i tried that. I thought I had it too but if the question number is 18 it would give me 0, meaning it'll end the round. needs to end after question 19 is answered so it can start at question 20 for the next round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about (x + 1) mod 10? If you offset by one you don't get 0 as a valid case.